# confuse about score filed in solr result

Tags: solr

I am little confuse with solr result. I have index **query** field

schema.xml configuration

```
<field name="question" type="text_query" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>


<fieldType name="text_query" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

      <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
         <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

I have index following 6 documents into solr

```
  [
            {
             "query": "who is gandhi",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 1
            },
            {
             "query": "who is person know as gandhi",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 2
            },
            {
             "query": "who is Sachin",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 3
            },
            {
             "query": "who is mahatma gandhi",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 4
            },
            {
             "query": "who is gandhis",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 5
            },
            {
             "query": "who are gandhi brothers",
             "source": "quora.com",
             "id" : 6
            }
]
```

When i search for ***query:"gandhi"*** i got result as

Response from solr

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 4,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 0.8048013,
    "docs": [
      {
        "query": "who is gandhi btothers",
        "id": "6",
        "source": "quora.com",
        "_version_": 1513810901444067300,
        "score": 0.8048013
      },
      {
        "query": "who is person know as gandhi",
        "id": "2",
        "source": "quora.com",
        "_version_": 1513810901436727300,
        "score": 0.643841
      },
      {
        "query": "who is gandhi",
        "id": "1",
        "source": "quora.com",
        "_version_": 1513810901428338700,
        "score": 0.5945348
      },
      {
        "query": "who is mahatma gandhi",
        "id": "4",
        "source": "quora.com",
        "_version_": 1513810901431484400,
        "score": 0.37158427
      }
    ]
  }
```

As per my configuration I think i should have get below result at top with **maxscore**

```
{
    "query": "who is gandhi",
    "id": "1",
    "source": "quora.com",
    "_version_": 1513810901428338700,
    "score": 0.5945348
}
```

**explain** field in debug

```
"explain": {
      "1": "\n0.5945348 = (MATCH) weight(query:gandhi in 0) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n  0.5945348 = score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:\n    0.99999994 = queryWeight, product of:\n      0.5945349 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)\n      1.681987 = queryNorm\n    0.5945349 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:\n      1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n        1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      0.5945349 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)\n      1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=0)\n",
      "2": "\n0.643841 = (MATCH) weight(query:gandhi in 0) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n  0.643841 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    1.287682 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=4)\n    0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=0)\n",
      "4": "\n0.37158427 = (MATCH) weight(query:gandhi in 1) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n  0.37158427 = score(doc=1,freq=1.0), product of:\n    0.99999994 = queryWeight, product of:\n      0.5945349 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)\n      1.681987 = queryNorm\n    0.3715843 = fieldWeight in 1, product of:\n      1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n        1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      0.5945349 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)\n      0.625 = fieldNorm(doc=1)\n",
      "6": "\n0.8048013 = (MATCH) weight(query:gandhi in 3) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:\n  0.8048013 = fieldWeight in 3, product of:\n    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n    1.287682 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=4)\n    0.625 = fieldNorm(doc=3)\n"
    }
```

But results are something different. Why is it so ? help Appreciated :)

Comment: why do you think so, because id=1 for that document?

Comment: no id is given by me only..I think it because query contains only three words , so unmatch words are less

Comment: Hey, I indexed six records which you have provided and getting the `{
        "query": "who is gandhi",
        "source": "quora.com",
        "id": 1,
        "score": 0.73895097
      },` as the first with high similarity score. What is solr version are you using? I have tested it on 5.2.1.

Comment: @YoungHobbit configuration you are using is same?

Comment: what is the content of stopword.txt. Previously I checked it with text_general type.

Comment: its a list of stopwords

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91061/discussion-between-younghobbit-and-3ppps).

Comment: You should add the parameter debugQuery=true which will give you detailed information about the computed score.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add what I think is the actual explaination - if you're doing sharding by yourself (aka "legacy mode"), the score is calculated by itself on each shard. When you have a small number of documents (or the documents are not randomly distributed across the shards), the score from each shard might not compare exactly as you think it should when retrieved to the final result.

It's not a configuration issue, just a consequence of the scores being calculated on each shard before being merged by the responding node.

The discrepancy should disappear As soon as shard#2 no longer have 50% more documents than shard#1 (the maxdoc= value in the debugQuery output). If you have a couple of million of documents, a difference of two documents doesn't do much, but when there's a 50% difference between the shards and what they contain, that will affect the score a lot more.

See "[Distributing Documents across Shards](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding)":

> In the legacy distributed mode, Solr does not calculate universal term/doc frequencies. For most large-scale implementations, it is not likely to matter that Solr calculates TD/IDF at the shard level. However, if your collection is heavily skewed in its distribution across servers, you may find misleading relevancy results in your searches. In general, it is probably best to randomly distribute documents to your shards.

If you switch to running in SolrCloud mode later, that part of the calculation should be done collection wise and not for each shard locally (as it's done in legacy mode with manual sharding).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem is with the algorithm of scoring.I don't have the same algorithm for my doc 1 any doc 2. The reason for different algorithm was multiple shards. If I use single shards I get the write ouput

```
"response": {
"numFound": 4,
"start": 0,
"maxScore": 1.1823215,
"docs": [
  {
    "query": "who is gandhi",
    "id": "1",
    "source": "quora.com",
    "_version_": 1513817219957522400,
    "score": 1.1823215
  },
  {
    "query": "who is mahatma gandhi",
    "id": "4",
    "source": "quora.com",
    "_version_": 1513817220025680000,
    "score": 0.73895097
  },
  {
    "query": "who are gandhi brothers",
    "id": "6",
    "source": "quora.com",
    "_version_": 1513817220027777000,
    "score": 0.73895097
  },
  {
    "query": "who is person know as gandhi",
    "id": "2",
    "source": "quora.com",
    "_version_": 1513817220023582700,
    "score": 0.5911608
  }
]
```

}
}